# Passing parameters to a downstream maven job?

Tags: maven, jenkins

With the Jenkins plugin "Parameterized Trigger Plugin" you can pass job parameters to a downstream job. You have to specify the downstream job which I don't know in my case.

In am using all maven jobs with the setting "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" enabled such that the downstream jobs are automatically detected and run by Jenkins it self.
A such, I don't know the downstream job such that I can't specify it when using the "Parameterized Trigger Plugin". 
How can I pass all parameters value's to all the detected jenkins maven jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I have to disappoint you. There is no way to add parameters to the `Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built`. There is a little manual work to do to "add this functionality":

- Go to the triggered Job with parameter
- Go to each `Upstream-Job` and add a post build action: `Trigger parameterized build on other projects`

Its not the ideal solution. But the plugin doesn't support this use case.